# What is the syntax of lftp's mirror -x (exclude) option?

Tags: ftp

I want to mirror a directory using `lftp` but I want to exclude certain subdirectories.

I tried

`mirror -R -e -x ^\.svn$ /documents/ /test`

and

`mirror -R -e -x /^\.svn$/ /documents/ /test`

but neither of them excluded the *.svn* directories.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`mirror -R -e -x ^\.svn$ /documents/ /test` is just fine.

The trick is, as *.svn* is a **directory** it will only be matched by a pattern that ends in a slash:

`mirror -R -e -x ^\.svn/$ /documents/ /test`

Answer (score 3):

From my experiments, it seems the include and exclude patterns are matched against the whole path with no initial / but with a trailing / for a directory.

Thus if you're trying to match a directory name like .svn which can occur at any level in the tree, you need this RE:

```
(^\|/).svn/
```

The ^ alternative matches .svn at the top level and the / alternative matches any level below that.

The | character is significant to lftp so needs to be sloshed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using

`--exclude /\..+/$`

to exclude all folders starting with a dot.